# Save metadata to jobs on Sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

Is it possible to save metadata to jobs when using Sidekiq?

For example, I want to execute a validation as a background job so that when it finishes, any errors encountered would be saved as metadata inside the job.

If this is possible, will I still be able to recover this metadata after the job is finished or dead?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not straight out of the box with Sidekiq, but I have accomplished this with [sidekiq-status](https://github.com/utgarda/sidekiq-status)

For example, in your scenario, it would look something like this:

```
class ValidatorJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidekiq::Status::Worker 

  def perform(*args)
    # Run validations

    # after they are done, you can store any data with the store method
    store attr1: 'failed'
  end
end
```

Comment: sidekiq-status use Sidekiq [_middleware_][1] and job _metadata_ hash to accomplish this. It is possible to do the same without this gem. [https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Middleware#custom-middleware]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Sidekiq provides *middleware* (client & server) and the possibility to add metadata to the job.

```
  def call(worker_class, job, queue, redis_pool)
    # return false/nil to stop the job from going to redis
    return false if queue != 'default'
    job['customer'] = Customer.current_id
    yield
  end
```

Check [this link](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Middleware#custom-middleware) for the docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can't recover any state of a job when it's finished.

Seems that in your case you will need to save or send the data to somewhere else (like the database) to read it later and take action.